# How to disable save button of pdf when it is rendered via visual force page?

Tags: pdf, salesforce

In Salesforce I have developed a visual force page and using it's renderAs property a page is rendered as PDF. While the rendered PDF gives all options such as Save, Print, etc. In this case I want to disable the SAVE button from end user to disallow him from saving the document on his local machine. Is it possible to do the same in salesforce? If it is possible, please provide the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not a Salesforce question, it's a PDF question.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf document viewed depends on the third party pdf viewer such as adobe reader and you cannot control another software from salesforce